# Generic view configurator

Tags: swift

I'm trying to solve something with generics in Swift, but I'm doing something wrong which I cannot seem to figure out. I have 2 views with the same ui components but they are visually different but the content is the same.

So I wanted to abstract the way I fill the view so I can reuse that code. (I simplified my example to the bare minimum).

```
protocol ViewConfigurator {
    associatedtype View: UIView

    init(view: View)

    func configure()
}

protocol PersonView: UIView {
    var nameLabel: UILabel { get }
}

class BigPersonView: UIView, PersonView {
    var nameLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500))
}

class SmallPersonView: UIView, PersonView {
    var nameLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 10))
}


class PersonViewConfigurator: ViewConfigurator {
    private let view: PersonView

    required init(view: PersonView) {
        self.view = view
    }

    func configure() {
        view.nameLabel.text = "Swift"
    }
}
```

But the error I get in playground is:

> Playground execution failed:
>
> error: MyPlayground.playground:24:7: error: type 'PersonViewConfigurator' does not conform to protocol 'ViewConfigurator'
>   class PersonViewConfigurator: ViewConfigurator {
>         ^
>
> MyPlayground.playground:4:20: note: unable to infer associated type 'View' for protocol 'ViewConfigurator'
>       associatedtype View: UIView
>                      ^
>
> MyPlayground.playground:27:14: note: candidate can not infer 'View' = 'PersonView' because 'PersonView' is not a class type and so can't inherit from 'UIView'
>       required init(view: PersonView) {

Which is weird (I think) because PersonView is a UIView right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you want a generic view you can do something like this:

```
protocol PersonView: UIView {
    static var nameLabel: UILabel {get}
}

class BigPersonView: UIView, PersonView {
    static var nameLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500))
}

class SmallPersonView: UIView, PersonView {
    static var nameLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 10))
}

class PersonViewConfigurator<T: PersonView> {
    public let testView: UILabel!
    init() {
        testView = T.nameLabel
    }

    public func configure() {
        testView.text = "swift"
    }
}

func test() {
    let person = PersonViewConfigurator<BigPersonView>()
    person.configure()
    print(person.testView.text)
}

test()
```

Also, Protocols follow strict rules and can't be used with inherited types. Which means if you ask for a UIView, you have to give it a UIView, if you ask for a PersonView, you have to give it a PersonView.

Which makes me wonder also why you have the associated type?

Here is your code as i described it:

```
protocol ViewConfigurator {
    init(view: PersonView)

    func configure()
}

protocol PersonView: UIView {
    var nameLabel: UILabel { get }
}

class BigPersonView: UIView, PersonView {
    var nameLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500))
}

class SmallPersonView: UIView, PersonView {
    var nameLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 10))
}


class PersonViewConfigurator: ViewConfigurator {

    required init(view: PersonView) {
        self.view = view
    }

    func configure() {
        view.nameLabel.text = "swift"
    }

    private let view: PersonView
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It works! The ViewConfigurator had an associated type because I use this protocol for other configurators.